# Python - Importing modules

Tags: python, module

given this folder structure:

```
search/
      __init__.py
      blogs.py
database/
      __init__
      tags.py
```

if I'm working at `tags.py`, how can I `import` a class called `crawler` inside `blogs.py`?

Comment: this can be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following in `tags.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from search.blogs import crawler
```

Comment: If you use four spaces instead of backticks for code blocks, you'll get syntax highlighting.